# Sustaining a spell with an instantaneous effect

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, sustained-powers

I'm having a problem understanding the [*Evil Eye*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=798) witch hex.

Its effect is pretty straightforward.

> Your fix your eye on the target, imposing a malevolent hex. The target becomes frightened based on the results of its Will save.

On a failed save, it's gets frightened 1.<sup>[1]</sup>

The catch is the the spell's duration can be sustained. What happens on subsequent rounds? The only thing that makes sense to me is that the frightened condition is re-applied each round the spell is sustained. Is that the case?

---

1. Or frightened 2 on a crit fail. This is not relevant to the question and hereby ignored.

Comment: Did you read the full text of Evil Eye?

Comment: @Ifusaso Apparently not!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the text in Evil Eye, the Duration is *not* instantaneous. It provides details about what happens while it is Sustained.

> **Saving Throw** Will; **Duration** sustained up to 1 minute
>
> Your fix your eye on the target, imposing a malevolent hex. The target becomes frightened based on the results of its Will save. **This condition value can't be reduced below 1 while the spell is active and you can see the target.** Regardless of the outcome, the target is then temporarily immune for 1 minute.

---

> Or frightened 2 on a crit fail. This is not relevant to the question and hereby ignored.

This is actually very relevant. Even on a Critical Failure, the target only remains Frightened 1 they can reduce the Frightened 2 Condition to 1 as normal.

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked that sentence each time. I would switch to the frightened page when I would reach that word and forget about the rest. /// Re "*This is actually very relevant*", Too what happens, sure. But not to the question. /// Thanks!